# Animate menu nav bar by adding class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, offset

I have a menu bar that I want to make animate when it gets out of a div box called "#main".

And I want it to animate back when it gets into the div box again and also a div box called "#about" as well. 
("#about" div box is placed right after "#main" div box.)

Below is how I coded and it works partially. It just doesn't animate back when it gets into "#about" div box.
How can I make it all work?

Thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var position = $(window).scrollTop;
  var mainPostion = $('#main').offset().top;
  var aboutPostion = $('#about').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    position = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (position > window.innerHeight - 40 && position > mainPostion) {
      $("#menu").addClass("animate-menu");
      $("nav img").addClass("animate-menu2");
      $("#logo").addClass("animate-menu3");
    } else if (position > window.innerHeight && position > aboutPostion) {
      $("#menu").removeClass("animate-menu");
      $("nav img").removeClass("animate-menu2");
      $("#logo").removeClass("animate-menu3");
    } else {
      $("#menu").removeClass("animate-menu");
      $("nav img").removeClass("animate-menu2");
      $("#logo").removeClass("animate-menu3");
    }
  });
});

<style>
#menu {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}
#menu.animate-menu { 
    animation-name: menuani;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes menuani {
    0%{ background: #303B40; }
    100%{
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        background: #5DC5C6;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
    #menu a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    nav ul { display: flex; }
        nav img {
            width: 60px;
            margin-top: 2px;
        }
        nav img.animate-menu2 { animation: logoani 0.5s 1 forwards; }
        @keyframes logoani {
            0%{ transform: scale(1.0); }
            100%{ transform: scale(0.69); }
        }
        #logo {
            flex-grow: 1;
            padding-left: 35px;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }
        #logo.animate-menu3 { animation: logoani2 0.5s 1 forwards; }
        @keyframes logoani2 {
            0%{  }
            100%{ padding-left: 20px; }
        }
#main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
#about {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you include your css please?

Comment: I just added my css. It's only some parts from my whole css and html files so if you need more info on html/css, let me know.